# Why does PHP7 extension memory-leaking?

Tags: memory-leaks, php-7, php-extension

**ANSWER**: because php 7.0.15 and php 7.0.6 if different in the way they working with refcounter: in php 7.0.15 zval_dtor() decrement the refcounter, in php 7.0.6 is does not.

I call the following `test_test` function in loop, 100000 iterations and see memory usage increasing.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; ++ $i ) {
    test_test();
    if ( 0 == $i % 10000 ) {
        echo memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The extension code:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(test_test)
{
    zval zzz;
    array_init(&zzz);

    if (Z_REFCOUNTED(zzz)) {

        if(Z_REFCOUNT(zzz) ) {
            // --- we do reach this line of code
            Z_DELREF(zzz); // (1)

        }

        if( 0 == Z_REFCOUNT(zzz) ) { // (2)
            // --- we do reach this line of code
            zval_dtor(&zzz);
        }
    }
}
```

When I remove (1) and (2) - no leank anymore. But these changes dont affect "zval_dtor()" call - it called in both scenarios.

(The more wild thing is that 2 different php7 machines behave differently: the problem exists only for one of them. I believe I have the same php7 version on both).

Comment: @ron This is using an extension, so that might be valid. Is it C or C++?

Comment: @tadman Indeed. I stand corrected.

Comment: This isn't even a question.

Comment: @ciruvan put more "?" at the end if you wish.

Comment: Well, it's a question and an answer. Still makes me wonder what kind of reactions you expect.